# Php code that can read a file from a folder and display it on a page

Tags: php

I want a div code to read a .txt file from a certain folder and it will display the .txt content on the div code.

E.I: If i upload a thisisatest.txt, with the contents of "This is a test" Date:"Whatever the date is" and the div will see that i uploaded the file to the said folder and it will display "This is a test, date posted: Whatever the date is". It will also display all the original .txts.

Currently i am using:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents("test.txt");
?>
```

It is working fine but i need it to see that if i post something lie {date} and the text following it will be displayed differently.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors have you run into?  This question as stated is too vague IMHO. Please see [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be using PHP inside your HTML code.
file_get_contents function will read the content of the file as it is.
nl2br will transform new lines to br for proper display in HTML.

```
<div>
<?php
   echo nl2br(file_get_contents(path_to_your_file));
?>
</div>
```